# Iterate JSON in a django template

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, django-email

I have a json coming from a view in below format ,

```
[  
    {  
        "model":"booking.bookeditem",
        "pk":192,
        "fields":{  
            "Booking_id":155,
            "hoarding":9,
            "date_from":"2017-11-21",
            "date_until":"2017-12-06",
            "price_net":"34500",
            "created":"2017-11-07T11:35:49.675Z"
        }
    }
]
```

I need to iterate through this json and print it in the template.Actually, I want to create an invoice email for the user after booking is performed for that I passed `bookeditems` as context to email templates.

Here is the view to create booking,

views.py :

```
def create_order(request,checkout):
    booking = checkout.create_order()
    if not booking:
        return None, redirect('cart:index')
    checkout.clear_storage()
    checkout.cart.clear()
    bookingitems = BookedItem.objects.filter(Booking_id=booking.pk)
    booking.send_invoice_email(booking,user,bookingitems)
    return booking, redirect('home')
```

Function to send invoice email,

```
def send_invoice_email(self,booking,user,bookingitems):
        customer_email = self.get_user_current_email()
        data = serializers.serialize('json',bookingitems)
        subject ="invoice"
        ctx = {
                 'hoardings':data
              }
        send_invoice.delay(customer_email, subject, ctx)
```

and i'm using `celery&django EmailMessage` to sending invoice email.

task.py:

```
@shared_task(name="task.send_invoice")
def send_invoice(customer_email, subject, ctx):
    to=[customer_email]
    from_email = 'example@gmail.com'
    message = get_template('email/invoice_email.html').render(ctx)
    msg = EmailMessage(subject,message,to=to,from_email=from_email)
    msg.content_subtype = 'html'
    msg.send()
```

I tried this :

```
 {% for i in hoardings %}
        <tr>
           <td>{{ i.pk }}</td>
        </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

But it is not working , and the loop are iterating for each and every string.

Where am i going wrong in the iteration? Please help..

Comment: `data` is serialized to a `JSON` string. I don't think you need to serialize `bookingitems`.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I'm getting this error with out serializing `EncodeError at /checkout/summary/ <QuerySet [CartLine(hoarding=<Hoarding: SKU-7 (CBT Bus terminal)>,date_from=datetime.date(2017, 11, 29), date_until=datetime.date(2017, 12, 7))]> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Actually, my comment was misleading. Data structures used in celery task need to be serialized. However, I don't understand why data isn't serialized to a `dict`. How is `serializers.serialize` implemented?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule imported serializer `from django.core import serializers`
 then  passed objects  `data = serializers.serialize('json',bookingitems)`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `list` of JSON objects so when you iterate over it, you get a `dict` in `i` variable. To access the data in list you have to iterate over items of it, using

```
{% for i in hoardings %}
    {% for k, v in i.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ k.pk }}</td> #or just v if you need only values displayed in template
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `Task task.send_invoice[47c9db50-2627-40f7-a062-f3cdaaf1b92f] raised unexpected: TemplateSyntaxError(u"Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'i.items()'",)'

Comment: Actually the parenthesis is a syntax error realy that's is why you're getting this exception back. 

the statement should really be: 
{% for i in hoardings %}
{% for k, v in i.items %}

Answer (score 0):

Why do you convert it into JSON? If you want to use it in the template, just pass it as a dictionary:

```
def send_invoice_email(self, booking, user, bookingitems):
    customer_email = self.get_user_current_email()
    subject ="invoice"
    ctx = {
        'hoardings': bookingitems
    }
    send_invoice.delay(customer_email, subject, ctx)
```

In your template:

```
{% for i in hoardings %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ i.pk }}</td>
       <td>{{ i.title }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't see the need to convert it to JSON first. That's the problem you have. It is passed to the template as a `string`, thus you cannot loop over it as if it were a dictionary. If you want to do that, you need to find a template tag or filter so the `JSON` is converted to a dictionary so you can loop over it like a regular dictionary.

Comment: I'm getting this error while passing object as context (without serializing)`EncodeError at /checkout/summary/
<QuerySet [CartLine(hoarding=<Hoarding: SKU-7 (CBT Bus terminal)>,date_from=datetime.date(2017, 11, 29), date_until=datetime.date(2017, 12, 7))]> is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 0):

Serialize `bookingitems` to a list of `OrderDict` items instead of a `JSON` string.

As plain Python objects, tasks are easily pickled and put on the task queue. Likewise, in this format the message broker is able to pass this task to the worker.

```
def send_invoice_email(self, booking, user, bookingitems):
    customer_email = self.get_user_current_email()
    data = serializers.serialize('python', bookingitems)
    subject = 'invoice'
    ctx = {
        'hoardings': data
    }
    send_invoice.delay(customer_email, subject, ctx)
```

In email template, loop over a list of `OrderDict`.

```
{% for queryset in hoardings %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ queryset.pk }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```